# How do I reset select and ng-select to first option dynamically

Tags: html, angular

UPDATE ::

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tggo2e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This stack is basically a TLDR of this post.

UPDATE 2::

Ok basically in that blitz, example 2 works. haha. in my code I was resetting that arr2 in my subscribe after the API call but doing it before the API call fixed it. Now I just have to figure out how to give it that first option (Pick something..) on initial load instead of a blank box.

///////////////////

So basically I have a cascade of select dropdowns. Lets call them form1, form2, form3.

When I select form1, it will call an API using that selection and dynamically give me an array to use for form2 options. same for form3,4,5,etc.

Now this is no problem up to here. But when I have selected form1,2,3 and then I select form1 again, I want form 2 and 3 to reset to my disabled option 1 but I can't seem to be able to get that to happen.

```
Component.ts

dropdownForm() {
  this.dropdownForm = new FormGroup({ 
    form1: new FormControl(),
    form2: new FormControl(),
    form3: new FormControl(),
    form4: new FormControl()
)}

callAPI(query) {
  // API CALL

}

changeONE(e) {

  // this.arr2 = [];

  // reset this.dropdownForm.form2 back to the first option 1('Pick something..) to be 'selected' and 'disabled' 

  // this.callAPI(e)
}

changeTWO(e) {
  // this.arr3 = []

  // reset this.dropdownForm.form3

  this.callAPI(e)
}

changeTHREE(e) {
  // this.arr4 = []

 // reset this.dropdownForm.form4 -- this one is ng-select so it is way different than the others.

 // this.callAPI(e)
}
```

```
HTML

<form [formGroup]="dropdownForm">

    <div>

      <div>
        <label for="form1">Form1</label>

        <select id="form1"
          (change)="changeONE($event)">
          <option [value]="" selected disabled>Pick something..</option>
          <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of arr">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="form2">Form2</label>

        <select id="form2"
          (change)="changeTWO($event)">
          <option [value]="" selected disabled>Pick something..</option>
          <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of arr2">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="form3">Form3</label>

        <select id="form3"
          (change)="changeTHREE($event)">
          <option [value]="" selected disabled>Pick something..</option>
          <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of arr3">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>


      <div>
        <label for="form4">Form4:</label>

        <ng-select [multiple]="true" placeholder="Pick something" (change)="changeFOUR($event)" >
          <ng-option *ngFor="let item of arr4">{{item}}</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
      </div>
```

I've tried adding formControlname in my selects but that makes the select act weird for some reason... maybe its because my 'new FormControl('')' is wrong? But it makes my form1,2,3 just preselect something random in my optionsArr.

And even then, if i do this.dropdownForm.controls.form1.reset() or something like that, it doesn't do anything. it will just reset the value instead of the resetting the dropdown box(which I'm not even using anyways.. haha. I should be but I'm using using that changeONE() and $event to get the value)

Thank you

EDIT::

I just tried

```
component.ts

this.dropdownForm.get('form2').reset() 

HTML

<select id="form1"
          (change)="changeONE($event)" formControlName='form1'>
```

And basically when I have form1 and form2 selected and I go back and select form1 with that this.dropdownForm.get('form2').reset(), it won't reset form2. Instead, it will select the first item in the new updated arr2 (after i get arr2 from that API call) on the second option of that select instead of going to that disabled option one.

Comment: The better way would be make use of ```valueChanges``` inside your ```ngAfterViewInit```
Make an API Call on every change, and if anyone changes reset the next dropdown.

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena sorry but the part I'm having trouble with is the resetting of the next dropdown to the first disabled option. For some reason I can't get it to work as I want for the life of me. Would you have any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Could you please update your example over ```stackblitz```. So that we can have a  deeper look into it,

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena Here is something very basic that is something that I am experiencing.  

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tggo2e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html